# How to build an ongoing alert that catches sudden spikes for a certain http error code?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I could really use an ongoing alert that catches a sudden rise (spike) in a certain error code (such as 404 or 502 etc...)
I tried giving this some thought on how to achieve that, and... Well... I could really use your help with the script :-)

From my understanding the search query should "know" or, "sense" the normal traffic (not sure for how long, maybe for 1hr, 2hrs) and alert when there is a spike in the error code compared to 1-2 hours ago.
I think the error code spike threshold should be more than 5% of total traffic, while occurring for longer than 90 seconds.

Here is a Splunk Query I use today, I appreciate your help tuning it to what I described above:

```
tag=NginxLogs host=www1 OR host=www2 |stats count by status|eventstats sum(count) as total|eval perc=round((count/total)*100,2)|where status="404" AND perc>5
```

Answer (score 0):

The top command automatically provides the count and percent.
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.1.2/SearchReference/Top

```
tag=NginxLogs host=www1 OR host=www2  
| top status
| search percent > 5 AND status > 399
```

If you have the url,http request method and user in your splunk logs, you can add it as a part of this alert. Example:

```
tag=NginxLogs host=www1 OR host=www2  
| eventstats distinct_count(userid) as NoOfUsersAffected by requestUri,status,httpmethod
| top status,httpmethod,NoOfUsersAffected by requestUri
| search NoOfUsersAffected > 2 AND ((status>499 AND percentage > 5) OR (StatusCode=400 AND percentage > 95))
```

You can use the following alert message:

```
$result.percent$ % ($result.count$ calls) has StatusCode $result.status$  for 
$result.requestUri$ - $result.httpmethod$.
$result.NoOfUsersAffected$ users were affected
```

You will get alert like:

```
21.19 % (850 calls) has StatusCode 500  for https://app.test.com/hello - GET.
90 users are affected
```